# Use multiple conflict_target in ON CONFLICT clause by reading from table

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

I have  3 tables table1,table2 .I need at insert into table1 table(t1_id is primary Key), use **ON CONFLICT** syntax and update other columns, but I can't able to update.

```
INSERT INTO table1
(t1_id,t1_date,t1_desc,...)
-- all column values of table2
ON CONFLICT ( t1_id) 
DO UPDATE 
SET 
-- update all old columns values to new column values of table2  except t1_id
```

Comment: error?.. `DO UPDATE SET t1_date='new val',t1_desc='new val' ` should work

Comment: I don't want to write manually.I need to read it from table2.

Comment: @PSM if you use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` (which you use I guess from your comment after `INSERT`) then you can use `SET col1 = EXCLUDED.col1` after `DO UPDATE`. Still, specifying columns one-by-one is a requirement of `UPDATE`.

Comment: @ pozs   I tried that one also .It gives Error.ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
SQL state: 42P10